# Dynamically Populating DataTables.net DataTable JQuery Plugin

Tags: jquery, datatables

I just downloaded [DataTables](http://datatables.net/index) and this plugin looks great!  I am however having an issue dynamically populating the plugin's DataTable component.  I'm able to populate the table if I have static  and 's in the  and static  and 's in the .  I would however like to dynamically build the ,  and  and populate the  and  entities.  The code below, replaces the static table contents with the XML parsed contents when you hit the enter button.  Any ideas on how to make this completely dynamic?  I tried adding the dataTable class to my table
$("table.display").addClass("dataTable");

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
        <title>DataTables example</title>
        <style type="text/css" title="currentStyle">
            @import "../../media/css/demo_page.css";
            @import "../../media/css/demo_table.css";
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../../media/js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../../media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#example').dataTable();
            } );
        </script>
    </head>
    <body id="dt_example">
        <div id="container">
            <table class="query">
                <tr>
                    <td class="status"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input class="query defaultText" type="text"
                        title="Type SQL query here, then press 'Enter' to execute...">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div class="full_width big">
                DataTables zero configuration example
            </div>          
            <div id="demo">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr> **//want to remove these**
                        <th>Rendering engine</th>//want to remove these
                        <th>Browser</th>//want to remove these
                        <th>Platform(s)</th>//want to remove these
                        <th>Engine version</th>//want to remove these
                        <th>CSS grade</th>//want to remove these
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="odd gradeX">**//want to remove these**
                        <td>Trident</td>//want to remove these
                        <td>Internet
                             Explorer 4.0</td>//want to remove these
                        <td>Win 95+</td>//want to remove these
                        <td class="center"> 4</td>//want to remove these
                        <td class="center">X</td>//want to remove these
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
            <div class="spacer"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**index.js:**

```
$(function () {
$("input.query").keyup(function (e) {
        // check if ENTER key was pressed
        if (e.keyCode == "13") { 
            var data = '<ns1:executeResponse xmlns:ns1="http://sqlws.test.com">' +
                           '<ns1:return>' + 
                               '<results>' +
                               '<row><deviceid>deviceid1</deviceid><domain>1</domain><role>manager</role><usage>100</usage></row>' +
                               '<row><deviceid>deviceid2</deviceid><domain>1</domain><role>director</role><usage>100</usage></row>' +
                               '</results>' +
                           '</ns1:return>' +
                       '</ns1:executeResponse>';

            var $xmlDoc = $($.parseXML(data));

            var $txt = $xmlDoc.find('ns1\\:return');

            var $firstrow = $txt.children("results").children(":first");

            var row;
             $("table.display thead").empty();
                    $("table.display tbody").empty();

            $("table.display").addClass("dataTable");

            row = $("<tr/>");
            row.append($("<th/>").text("#"));

            $firstrow.children().each(function(){
                row.append($("<th/>").text(this.nodeName));
            });

            row.appendTo($("table.display thead"));

            var ndx = 0;
            $txt.children("results").children().each(function () {
                row = $("<tr class='odd gradeX'/>");
                row.append($("<td/>").text(ndx + 1));
                $(this).children().each(function () {
                    row.append($("<td/>").text($(this).text()));
                    row.appendTo($("table.display tbody"));
                });
                ndx++;
            });

            if (ndx == 0) {
                // no rows returned
                $("table.display thead").empty();
                $("table.display tbody").empty();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataTables have special API to add data to table in runtime:

```
t.fnClearTable();
t.fnAddData(data);
```

where `data` is an array of arrays with table data, listed by rows:

```
[[r1c1, r1c2, …, r1cn],
  …
 [rmc1, rmc2, …, rmcn]]
```

Here, `n` is the number of your columns and `m` is the number of rows you're adding.
You can build the `data` with any data you want and then push it to the datatable using `fnAddData()` method.

Comment: how would I add to the thead vs the tbody?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding question regarding building table dynamically correctly, you will want to use JSON as data format. Follow example for [Server Side Processing](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) and you can set `aAJaxDataSource` option to be a url on server to handle all the data flow such as self creating table on page load, updates etc

Comment: I can't use JSON, my datasource is a SOAP web service endpoint, so I have to process the data as XML